# Passing multiple parameters in ajax call

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, asp.net-mvc-3

I am having having problem with sending the an object and two parameter in an ajax call.

My Server side method:

```
public ActionResult AddUpdate(string model, bool IsEdit, string Type)
{
//Do something
}
```

Client side ajax call is:
I am fetching all form values provided by user and saving them into "MemberObj" and sending  another 2 parameters ie IsEdit and Type. but at server side i am getting only the IsEdit and Type values model parameter is null. The date value in ajax call after stringify is like:

```
"{"model":{"id":"123","Name":"Jhon Doe","Relation":"Father","Dob":"15-3-2014","Address":"abc":" abc","City":"abc","MobileNumber":"1234567890"},"IsEdit":false,"Type":"FamilyMember"}"


var MemberObj={};
MemberObj.Name="aaa";
var requestJSONData={ "model": MemberObj, "IsEdit": IsEdit, "Type": str[0] }
$.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        url: '/Employee/AddUpdate',
        data: JSON.stringify(requestJSONData)
        success: function (msg) {
            //Success
        },
        error: function (msg) {

        }
    });
```

Any help is most appericiate.
Thanks

Comment: Try not stringifying it, jQuery accepts objects as data.

Comment: It's not really clear what `isEdit` and `str` is ?

Comment: You're sending model as an object , but the function prototype says it should be a string.

Answer (score 0):

in one of my projects i used the following line and it works like a charm:

```
  data: "{'sid':'" + sid.toString() + "'}",
```

try adapting yours to this format, it should work.

Comment: Thanks all for your quick responses. by stringifying MemberObj resolved my issue. JSON.stringify(MemberObj)